# How to send object to controller from Kendo Grid dataSource?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a kendo grid and its using a kendo dataSource, I am not used to using the kendo dataSource, to do inline editing, typically I would never do inline editing but I was requested to do so.

My dataSource is as follows

```
function PriceLookupGridDataSource() {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../KendoGridTesting/GetThePriceLookupGrid",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: function(item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    return "../KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject?myObj=" + item; 
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "MaterialTypeID",
                fields: {
                    VendorID: { type: "number" },
                    VendorName: { type: "string" },
                    Description: { type: "string" },
                    MaterialTypeID: { type: "number" },
                    MaterialType: { type: "string" },
                    ServicePrice: { type: "string" },
                    SellUOM: { type: "string" },
                    Cost: { type: "string" },
                    PurchaseUOM: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        batch: false,
        pageSize: 20
    });

    return dataSource;
}
```

The controller method that is used for the transport update is

```
[HttpPost]
public void PassAnObject(PriceLookupGrid myObj)
{
    ...
}
```

The object is

> Object {VendorID: 26, VendorName: "ACME STONE MASONRY", Description: "Special Stone Quote", MaterialTypeID: 35, MaterialType: "Cladding"…}

and the PriceLookupGrid data class is

```
public class PriceLookupGrid
    {
        public int VendorID { get; set; }
        public string VendorName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int MaterialTypeID { get; set; }
        public string MaterialType { get; set; }
        public string NewPrice { get; set; }
        public string RemodelPrice { get; set; }
        public string ServicePrice { get; set; }
        public string SellUOM { get; set; }
        public string Cost { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseUOM { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to pass this over to my controller I get an error

> GET http://localhost:51193/KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject?id=[object%20Object]&V….0000&ServicePrice=0.0000++++&SellUOM=Each&Cost=0.0000&PurchaseUOM=EachBBB 404 (Not Found)

Its passing the "item" over as seperate parameters and I don't want that happening.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `item` is an object, as you can see in your console. You can't just concat it in an url string. You to parse it. It haves an property called `models` with all changed(or *dirty*) rows of your grid which would be sent to the server.

In order to make ASP.Net MVC to bind your data into your Model, you have to send the date like:

```
../KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject?VendorID=1&VendorName=...
```

A simple way to *"parse"* your data into an url is this:

```js
var model = {VendorID: 26, VendorName: "ACME STONE MASONRY", Description: "Special Stone Quote", MaterialTypeID: 35, MaterialType: "Cladding"};

function modelToUrlParams(model) {
  var params = [];
  
  Object.keys(model).forEach(key => params.push(key + "=" + model[key]));
  
  return encodeURI("?" + params.join("&"));
};

var myUrl = "../KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject" + modelToUrlParams(model);

console.log("Final Url", myUrl);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but keep getting an error in the console and it won't hit the method in my controller

Comment: @Chris what error? Does it at least opens the request?

Comment: it parses it the way thats expected but the error is a 404
GET http://localhost:51193/KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject?VendorID=26&VendorName….0000&ServicePrice=0.0000++++&SellUOM=Each&Cost=0.0000&PurchaseUOM=EachBBB 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I have double checked and even copy and pasted the method name. I got break points and it just doesn't want to hit the method

Comment: Anyway you can provide the why this needs to be done for MVC to bind the data?

Comment: @Chris I have no resource about it, but mvc needs to know the property name and value. It's like any other web api language.

Answer (score 3):

Your Action is decorated with `[HttpPost]`, as it should be, but your error message indicates that you're doing a `GET`. You need Kendo to `POST` the data, instead:

```
update: {
    url: "../KendoGridTesting/PassAnObject",
    type: "post" 
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, sir.

Comment: Very nice catch.

Comment: Yes sir it did.

Comment: Oh, but the other answer is set as accepted @Chris ...?

Comment: Yes, without the other answer then I wouldn't be able to pass over the data correctly. If the other answer was never posted then I would never have been able to pass the data correctly

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to manually pass in the data - kendo takes care of it, which is why I removed the parameter from the url for the update - maybe give that a try?